# Populating the PrimaryIdentity in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, security

I'm using simple HTTP headers to pass a token to a WCF service for authentication (The WCF service is required to use the basicHTTPBinding, so I unfortunately cannot use the canned ws-security implementation). I would like to populate the PrimaryIdentity object so the WCF services can examine it to determine the authenticated user.

The issue is that the `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity` property is read-only at the time I'm trying to populate it. I've tried using SecurityTokenAuthenticators and IAuthorizationPolicy objects to set the identity info, but that route seems to require the use of message-level security (such as always sending in a username and password), which isn't what I want.

Can anyone shed light on how I could set the PrimaryIdentity field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PrimaryIdentity` is not intended to be populated by you - it's the WCF runtime's job to determine who's calling, and set the `PrimaryIdentity` accordingly.

So if you're calling with Windows credentials, then you'll get a `WindowsIdentity` stored there; if you're using ASP.NET membership providers, you'll get that caller stored into the `PrimaryIdentity`.

The only way you could actually set this is by creating your own custom server-side authentication mechanism and plug that into WCF.

See:

- [WCF Authentication Service Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx)
- [Fundamentals of WCF Security - Authentication, Authorization, Identities](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0611051&page=3)
- [WCF Custom Authentication and Impersonation](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2005/12/08/432658.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

You can create a class that implments [IAuthorizationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.iauthorizationpolicy.aspx). WCF parses all the identity tokens (X509, WS-Security Username/pass, etc.) and puts them in the evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"] which you get in the Evaluate function. This will return a List to you. If you replace this list with a list containing your own class that implements [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx) then WCF will read that into `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity`. please ensure that the list only contains one item otherwise you will confuse WCF and `PrimaryIdentity.Name` will be the empty string.

```
var myIdentity = new MyIdentity("MyId", otherstuff);
evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"] = new List<IIdentity> {myIdentity};
```

Also, you may want to process/read any of the tokens before you replace them.

```
var identities = evaluationContext.Properties.ContainsKey("Identities")
                                 ? (List<IIdentity>) evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"]
                                 : new List<IIdentity>();

var genericIdentity = identities.Find(x => x.AuthenticationType == "MyUserNamePasswordValidator");
```

`genericIdentity.Name` --> contains the username from WSS username token.

You would need a UsernamePasswordValidator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx) if you are using WS-Security Username token and do not want any default WCF validation. Since, we have a DataPower device that validates the token before the message gets to our service, we don't need to validate the username and password. In our case it just returns true.

Comment: While your answer is definitely useful, it raises even more questions. Where does the "Identities" magic string come from? Why would a list with more than one item "confuse" WCF? Most importantly, where did you get all this information from since there is nothing related to this in the official documentation?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me... First setup the authentication behavior of the host (here shown through code, but can also be done in config):

```
ServiceAuthorizationBehavior author = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthorizationBehavior>();
author.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new FormCookieServiceAuthorizationManager();
author.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
author.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = new List<IAuthorizationPolicy> { new CustomAuthorizationPolicy() }.AsReadOnly();
```

And then the helper classes

```
  internal class FormCookieServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
  {
     public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext)
     {
        ParseFormsCookie(operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage);
        return base.CheckAccess(operationContext);
     }
     private static void ParseFormsCookie(Message message)
     {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        if (httpRequest == null) return;

        string cookie = httpRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie)) return;

        string regexp = Regex.Escape(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName) + "=(?<val>[^;]+)";
        var myMatch = Regex.Match(cookie, regexp);
        if (!myMatch.Success) return;

        string cookieVal = myMatch.Groups["val"].ToString();
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookieVal);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), new string[0]);
     }
  }
  internal class CustomAuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
  {
     static readonly string _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     public string Id
     {
        get { return _id; }
     }

     public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
     {
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"] = new List<IIdentity> { Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity };
        return true;
     }

     public ClaimSet Issuer
     {
        get { return ClaimSet.System; }
     }
  }
```

And for when AspNetCompatibility is set, then `FormCookieServiceAuthorizationManager` is slightly simpler:

```
 internal class FormCookieServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
 {
    public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
       Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
       return base.CheckAccess(operationContext);
    }
 }
```