# client certificates take over the PrimaryIdentity

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate

I am using a few types of wcf services,
one of them is signed.
usually i get the client user name from the :

## ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name

now, when it got the signed service, the primary identity becames the X509 certificate..
The Windows identity is of anonymos or somthing like it..

what is the correct way to send both, certificate and regular identity.
or, how to get the user name.. ?

thak you all.

Answer (score 2):

That means that your service uses security settings with `clientCredentialsType="Certificate"`. This certificate is used as identification of your clients. If you want to use `UserName` or `Windows` authentication why do you use certificate? Message will be signed always if you use secure configuration (either transport or message security).

It is possible to pass both certificate and user name but it requires complete custom binding developed in code where user name will be passed as supporting token. I'm not sure if WCF supports this to the level to fill `PrimaryIdentity` for you from the supporting token.

Comment: what you are saying is, that if you sign the service, wcf wont let u see who the user is ? unless, develope a specific code for that.. what is the correct way to see only the user name, i dont need to authorize him.. just log his name, thanks.

Comment: No that is not what I'm saying. Setting `clientCredentialType` to something else doesn't mean that the message will not be sign. That is the big theory around different security configuration and used algorithms.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you want user authorize or not - you want him authenticate because only if user is authenticated you can see his user name. But you instruct the service to authenticate requests by certificates. No user name or windows account is ever transferred in your configuration.

Comment: And what kind of example do you expect? I just told you that you cannot use `Certificate` as client credentials if you want to get user name. There is one corner situation I forgot to mention - certificate can be mapped to a user in active directory. In case of transport security IIS can automatically resolve this and use correct user from active directory but I have never used this.

Comment: an example of **not** using the certificate as the client credentials, plus the way of taking the user name, but, ofcourse, the service should still be signed.. appreciate it. ----  _No that is not what I'm saying. Setting clientCredentialType to something else doesn't mean that the message will not be sign_

Comment: Here you have full example: http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Username%20Authentication%20with%20the%20SQL%20Membership%20Provider%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

If you have your client certificates mapped in AD, then you can get it by setting

system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication property to True.

This will work in IIS 7.x only. i dont know the equivalent setting in IIS 6 . but i assume there is some setting for AD Client Certificate mapping.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I am using a custom binding in the web.config to do both X509 certificate and WSS Username token. You do not need to develop the custom binding in code. It can be done in the config file. You may want to use both certificates and Username token because you may have a thingy (eg. Datapower, Biztalk, whatever) between your client and your service. And you need to authenticate both the client and the thingy in the middle.

Here is my custombinding ...

```
<customBinding>
                <binding name="MySvcBindingConfiguration">
                    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
                        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
                        <secureConversationBootstrap />
                    </security>
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="524288" maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
```

Please refer to my answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830294/populating-the-primaryidentity-in-wcf) regarding `PrimaryIdentity.Name`. You can totally customize `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity` by using a custom AuthorizationPolicy.

In the Evaluate function of you AuthorizationPolicy, you will see multiple identities in the evaluation context. You can replace them with your own custom identity and then WCF will put that identity in `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity`. Please ensure that there is only one identity in the list when you put it back in the evaluationContext.
Also, if you require SSL and client certifcates in IIS Website or VDir, then it will show up as an X509Identity in the evaluationContext.

```
var myCertIdId = identities.Find(x => x.AuthenticationType == "X509");

            var myCertThumbprint = myCertIdId != null
                                     ? myCertIdId.Name.Substring(myCertIdId.Name.LastIndexOf(';') + 2)
                                     : "";

            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            var certCol =
                store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, myCertThumbprint, false);

            store.Close();

var myCert = certCol[0];
```

myCert is the certificate from the certificate store ... you may want to check the count on the collection and if the count is 0 then throw an exception or something.